# How can I pass variable to ng-init call?

Tags: angularjs

At my controller's I have created a function that's responsible for initialising the state of the scope. It is then called at `ng-init` like so: `... ng-init="init(value)"` where `value` is some variable from the global scope. The problem is - it doesn't work. Doesn't angular allow to pass variables? Is anything within `ng-init` only evaluated without any context and I have to prepare a string?

Comment: Is init() also a variable from the scope?

Comment: Yep, ``init`` is defined a function of the scope at the controller's body

Answer (score 13):

I'm sure this is not the "right" thing to do, but it works and I use it.

Set a global variable on window..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.myCtrlData = {\"a\": \"It's a duck!\"};
</script>
```

..then pass the name of the variable to your controller using ng-init..

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="init('myCtrlData')">
```

..then retrieve the global variable inside of init()

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.init = function (dataKey) {
        if (dataKey && window[dataKey]) {
            var data = window[dataKey];

            // add data to scope
            angular.extend($scope, data);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work try replacing `value` with `"hello"` and you'll see it works, maybe it's something to do with value not being defined, you should try `init('{{value}}')` and see what that does if not then you need to find out why `value` is not defined.

Comment: Using template (`{{ value }}`) needs the value to be already defined at the scope. Passing inline string is not what I have asked about (I know I can pass expression that would be evaluated, am asking if it is possible to pass variable from global scope)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, posting answer to my own question.

Quick answer: You don't.

`ng-init` accepts only variables that are already at the scope. Or you can create one inline. I actually was doing that for a while (passing stringified json variable) but it didn't work well for some data (consider following json: `ng-init='"{\"a\": \"It's a duck!\"}'"`)

The proper solution is to create a service that would use and pass global variables. Am not sure if that's **much** better but I guess it's still better than using globals at the controller.